# create a webservice in java which connects to database and responds with a XML

Tags: java, web-services

I need to create a web service which can connect to database to retrieve a result-set and respond back in `XML`.

Which is the best way in terms of scalability & speed of development to achieve the above?

And also i should be able to generate client code without `Axis` automatically in `Eclipse` by using the `WSDL` of the web-service I create.

Please point me to some good, complete tutorials.

Thanks

Comment: What version of WSDL are you planning to implement?

Comment: Don't know about that.Please suggest one.

Comment: I would ask you to go WSDL 1.2 and higher, but that will require you to know JAXB and generating WSDL from JAXB annotations (by using, e.g. Apache CXF).

Comment: Ok i will go through them.please suggest a step-by-step approach as i am completely new to web-service development.

Comment: I have a doubt.will eclipse use Axis to generate web-service client? please clarify.

Comment: That depends. If you want to create WSDL version 1, then Axis is good for you, else Apache CXF for WSDL where you use XML annotations on your class (beans).

Comment: oh,can you point me to any tutorial on this?

Comment: Can we use eclipse to generate the client without axis?

Comment: Ok, this question is becoming too complex. Break down the question in a structure that's easy for us and for you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you *need* SOAP, is it in your requirements? If not, consider using REST via JAX-RX (Jersey), JAXB, and JPA for the database; I've had phenomenal results.

Answer (score 0):

[A tutoiral for the XML part (Jaxb)](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JAXB/article.html)

[Another tutorial for more details.](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)

[a quick overview about jax ws](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/)

In general you load your data as beans with jpa/hibernate but add xml annotations for the automatic marshelling/unmarshelling to build the response xml.

The rest is done (the transmission and the incoming call) with jax ws.
Normally you only have to implement the endpoint, the rest can be generated by the wsdl.

Step by step:

1. start like usual implementing your web app infra structure (data beans, dao, services)
2. add xml annotations (mind the dangerous backrefrences obj1 references obj2 references obj1, use XMLTransient annotation for members AND getter methods to avoid those references)
3. write the wsdl/get the wsdl from the customer or partner
4. generate the classes
5. implement the endpoint (the actual functionality)
6. repeat steps 2 to 5 until your customes stops changing the specificiation ;-)